# How to keep WCF Soap Service Open for the duration of the program running

Tags: c#, wcf

I am working on an C# WCF project and I have got it pretty much working except for quite a big but hopefully simple problem.

The WCF service is hosted from within my Console application and my console application calls a function to a different class to open the connection for the WCF service.

However, if the last line of the function is host.open(); the function call then finishes to the connection gets closed and the service can no longer be used. However, if I put Console.ReadLine() after the host.open then the service stays open and I can use it but obviously the rest of the flow of the program no longer runs.

Below is the code I am using to open the host connection.

```
public void startSoapServer()
        {
            string methodInfo = classDetails + MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod().Name;
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Configuration.soapServerSettings.soapServerUrl) ||
                Configuration.soapServerSettings.soapPort == 0)
            {
                string message = "Not starting Soap Server: URL or Port number is not set in config file";
                library.logging(methodInfo, message);
                library.setAlarm(message, CommonTasks.AlarmStatus.Medium, methodInfo);
                return;
            }
            //baseAddress = new Uri(string.Format("{0}:{1}", Configuration.soapServerSettings.soapServerUrl, 
            //    Configuration.soapServerSettings.soapPort));
            baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:6525/hello");

            using (ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(SoapServer), baseAddress))
            {
                ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
                smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
                smb.MetadataExporter.PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Policy15;
                host.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);
                host.Opened += new EventHandler(host_Opened);
                host.Faulted += new EventHandler(host_Faulted);
                host.Open();
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
```

Without the Console.ReadLine() there the function finishes so the connection closes. How can I keep the host open for the duration that the C# is app is running.

This function call is called from within the Main method halfway through initiliasing some stuff within the console stuff.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare ServiceHost at class scope instead of function scope and do not use `using`.

`using {}` will automatically Dispose the object to which it pertains and Disposal means closing. Also, since your ServiceHost is defined at function scope, it will go out of scope as soon as the function finishes and will be cleaned up by the garbage collector.

The reason that your `ReadLine` call is preventing the closing is because it is inside the using statement and stops the program inside the function where the variable is declared keeping it in scope.

You need to do something like this:

```
private ServiceHost host;

public void startSoapServer()
        {
            // trimmed... for clarity


                host = new ServiceHost(typeof(SoapServer), baseAddress));

                ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
                smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
                smb.MetadataExporter.PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Policy15;
                host.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);
                host.Opened += new EventHandler(host_Opened);
                host.Faulted += new EventHandler(host_Faulted);
                host.Open();

           // etc.
```

You will close `host` when you exit the application.

Comment: Thanks so obvious now. Thanks for your help